# Facial tracking

Tags: tracking, fcurves

I've been playing around with facial tracking. Placing markers on my face, then tracking it in blender. Once I hit "Link Empty to track" It creates the markers and they follow my facial movement. Each marker has a "follow track" constraint. I'm trying to resolve that into key frames. I hit the "Constraint to F-curve", but nothing happens. I don't see an error message at the top and no keyframes are created for that marker.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the "current cache to bake" button help? I often forget about it when I do physics, and it tends to give similar symptoms.

Comment: I believe that's for physics simulation. I don't have any physics. I simply added some trackers to footage. Each tracker has a follow constraint, but I can't get that resolved into keyframes.